# Problem with Geometric Progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

*Question: An infinite geometric progression has a finite sum. Given that the first term is 18 and that the sum of the first 3 terms is 38. Calculate the values of (i)the common ratio, (ii) the sum to infinity.*

What I'm doing:

Sum $s= \cfrac{a(r^n -1)}{r-1}$

$38  = 18\cfrac{r^3 -1}{r-1}$

$38r - 38 = 18r^3 - 18$

$18r^3 - 38r + 20 = 0$

???

Comment: Seems to be geometric progression, but title says arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{hint}$

The first $3$ terms are
$$
a+ar+ar^2 = 38
$$
where $a=18$ now we have to sum to infinity we utilize a well known fact
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}ar^n = \frac{a}{1-r}
$$ 
where $|r|<1$ which is important for the first calculation for finding $r$.

Comment: thanks  

I havent started solving the b) part yet...  

though shouldnt *a + ar + ar^2 = 38* (what you did) be equal to *[ 18 (r^3 -1)] / (r-1)]* (what Im doing)  

(And Im still in high school and my math sucks:) does that E thing stand for sum?

Comment: As @RossMillikan pointed out you have a root that corresponds to $1-r$ so if you use long division you will find that $$\frac{r^3-1}{r-1} = 1+r+r^2$$ you will yield the desired result. I think its easier to use the three terms of the series rather than the $n$ sum.

Comment: further more you can see (try it yourself - I wish I tried doing such things back then) if you can generalize to $$\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}=?$$

Comment: thanks.
  
btw, how do you do that separate line thingy? Im still kinda knew to stackexchange

Comment: use double $\$$ signs. Also look at this [mathjax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 3):

**i)**

The factor theorem tells us that $r-1$ is a factor. So you can use long division to get the quadratic factor: $$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{r}
   18r^2+18r-20  \\[-3pt]
r-1 \enclose{longdiv}{18r^3+0r^2-38r+20} \\[-3pt]
\underline{18r^3-18r^2}\phantom{2} \\[-3pt]
                    -20r+20  \\[-3pt]
         \underline{0}
\end{array}
$$
$$18r^3 - 38r + 20 = 0$$
$$\implies (r-1)(18r^2+18r-20)=0$$
$$\implies (r-1)\left(r-\frac23 \right)\left(r+\frac53 \right)=0$$
$$\implies r=1,-\frac53,\frac23$$ but since $-1 \lt r \lt 1 \implies r=\frac23$

**ii)**

$S_{\infty}=\cfrac{a}{1-r}=\cfrac{18}{1-\frac23}=54$

Comment: I dont really get how you broke down 
  
$18r^3 - 38r + 20 = 0$
  
into
  
$\implies (r-1)(18r^2+18r-20)=0$ ....

Comment: @thezaynthe I used long division

Comment: @thezaynthe I added some detail on the long division

Comment: thanks! I remember learning how to do this about 6 or 7 months ago for my Cambridge exams..

Comment: @thezaynthe Do you understand the factor theorem that I used to deduce $r-1$ is a factor? If not I can explain it in my answer also.

Comment: I dont really remember long division so Im trying to look it up
[from wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Do-Long-Division)
  

  
,was there any alternative to long division? I think there was but I dont remember much about it...

Comment: @thezaynthe Yep, the alternative was to use the fact that $
a+ar+ar^2 = 38$. As Ross and Chinny suggested

Comment: thanks, Ill try looking it up from my copy from last year to understand it better.
  
btw, can you line break in comments?
  
and do you have to tag users in every single comment? (like for example, do I have to tag you here while replying to you)

Comment: @thezaynthe yes unfortunately otherwise I will not know I have a message

Comment: oh, sorry for not tagging you before.

Comment: and can you add a line break in the comments?

Answer (score 2):

You have not used the fact that $r-1$ is a factor of your polynomial, which will get you a quadratic.  For three terms it is easier to write $18(1+r+r^2)=38$ and you start with the quadratic.  To have a finite sum you need $|r|\lt 1$, which gives you which root to use.